# Assigning methods to action won't clear previous assigned methods

Tags: c#

I have this function that i call multiple times so i need to wipe the assigned actions and make sure they don't duplicate:

My OnClick looks like this:

```
public class Input {
    public Action<Vector3> OnClick; 
}
```

Then in a different class I have:

```
// _input is a refence to class Input
public void Init()
{        
    _input.OnClick -= OnLeftClick;
    _input.OnClick += OnLeftClick;

    var list = _input.OnClick.GetInvocationList();

    var list = _input.OnClick.GetInvocationList();
    Debug.Log("DEBUG: " + list.Length);
    foreach (var item in list)
        Debug.Log(item.Method.ToString());
}
```

After calling this function a few times in a row the output gives:

```
DEBUG: 1
Void OnLeftClick(Vector3)
DEBUG: 2 
Void OnLeftClick(Vector3)
Void OnLeftClick(Vector3)
DEBUG: 5
Void OnLeftClick(Vector3)
Void OnLeftClick(Vector3)
Void OnLeftClick(Vector3)
Void OnLeftClick(Vector3)
Void OnLeftClick(Vector3)
```

So my method OnLeftClick is getting called multiple times, but I don't know why. How do you clear the method from the action so I can then re-assign it to prevent duplicates?

Comment: Do you call your method from multiple threads? Maybe when OnClick is null, two threads first remove `OnLeftClick` and then they both add it, and as a result the method is added two times to the event handler.

Comment: I've added the OnClick definition. As for `GetInvocationList` thats build into C# i don't know the code for that?
@SomeBody I'm not using multi threading its as simple as the code is shown above.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], otherwise we are just throwing guesses around.

Comment: @nvoigt other than putting a class around OnClick field and getting a reference to it - thats as simple as my code is already. It's assigning the `OnLeftClick` multiple times every time I call `Init` theres no hidden code to show here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; for me it prints "DEBUG: 1" every time. Is there any other place where you access `OnClick`?

Comment: Are you a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: @Sweeper no i am not.

Comment: @KlausGütter hmm its the only place in my setup.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of "different class" or the `Input` class?

Comment: @Steve As you probably already know, it's likely a [`Delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate). That's a `System.Runtime` type. And that's the whole reason for this happening.

Comment: To understand the issue with different targets, assuming you do not have a bad override of `GetHashCode()`, you can use the hash as an indicator that can discriminate between instances with great probability. So you could do `Debug.Log("I am " + GetHashCode());` and inside your `foreach` loop, do `Debug.Log("Target instance is " + item.Target.GetHashCode());`. This makes comment by Klaus Gütter and answer below by DDomen more clear, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

When `public Action<Vector3> OnClick;` is not marked `event`, i.e. it is a pure field, everyone has access to it in its entirety (not just through `add` and `remove` accessors). So they can clear it with `_input.OnClick = null;`.

However, are you sure you do not want an event?

For delegates, the convention is that a `null` reference is used (rather than some empty object) when there are no functions.

If instead you decide for an auto-event (so-called field-like event), access to the automatic (implicit) backing field is only from inside the class itself. Of course you can create a method in the class that clears the event, and make the method nonprivate, but maybe it is not the best design.

Comment: I am not sure if i want a event or an action? The difference between them seem so minor i couldn't tell which to use. But I am not assigning null anywhere as that might wipe all assignments from other classes in future which i don't want to do. However shouldn't `-=` be removing my method?

Comment: @WDUK Sure, `-=` will remove the (last) occurrence of your method from the delegate (or in case of an event, call the `remove` accessor which is usually designed to perform the same operation on the backing delegate field). See [Delegate removal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/subtraction-operator).

Comment: "will remove the (last) occurrence of your method" - to be more exact, if the method is not static, it will remove the last instance the method registered for the same instance

Comment: @KlausGütter Yeah, that is a good point. Two delegates are considered equal if the target (instance) and method are the same. It can become tricky for anonymous functions (like lambdas). Who knows if your comment is relevant to the problem the asker reports.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `OnClick` event subscribers are different from one `Init` call to another. Probably you are invoking the `Init` method on different objects or reference.

I hope this example clarify the situation:

```c#
class A {
   public Action<Vector3> OnClick;
   // using method group
   public A() : this(_OnClick) { }
   // using anonymous method/action reference
   public A(Action<Vector3> a) => OnClick = a;
   ...
   public void Init() {
      _init.OnClick -= OnClick;
      _init.OnClick += OnClick;
   }
   public void _OnClick(Vector3 v) { }
}
```

Problem with group method

```c#
A a1 = new A();
a1.Init();
// I will display the subscriber list like: _init.OnClick -> []
// Here you are applying:
//   _init.OnClick -= a1.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ ]
//   _init.OnClick += a1.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ a1.OnClick ]
// the subscriber is a1
A a2 = new A();
// But here you are applying:
//   _init.OnClick -= a2.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ a1.OnClick ]
//   _init.OnClick += a2.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ a1.OnClick, a2.OnClick ]
// the subscriber is a2
a2.Init();
```

Problem with anonymous methods

```c#
A a = new A(v => Console.WriteLine($"A1: {v}"));
a.Init();
// Here you are applying:
//   _init.OnClick -= a.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ ]
//   _init.OnClick += a.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ (v => Console.WriteLine($"A1: {v}")) ]
// the subscriber is (v => Console.WriteLine($"A1: {v}"))
a.OnClick = v => Console.WriteLine($"A2: {v}");
a.Init();
// But here you are applying:
//   _init.OnClick -= a.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ (v => Console.WriteLine($"A1: {v}")) ]
// and a.OnClick is (v => Console.WriteLine($"A2: {v}"))
//   _init.OnClick += a.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ (v => Console.WriteLine($"A1: {v}")), (v => Console.WriteLine($"A2: {v}")) ]
// the subscriber is (v => Console.WriteLine($"A2: {v}"))
a2.Init();
```

NOTE: it also occurs with the same "lambda body" but different anonymous method:

```
Action<Vector3> m1 = v => Console.WriteLine($"A: {v}");
Action<Vector3> m2 = v => Console.WriteLine($"A: {v}");
// m1 differs from m2 because are compiled to two different
// anonymous methods, even if they have the same code
a.OnClick = m1;
a.Init();
// Here you are applying:
//   _init.OnClick -= a.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ ]
//   _init.OnClick += a.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ m1 ]
// the subscriber is m1
a.OnClick = m2;
// But here you are applying:
//   _init.OnClick -= a.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ m1 ]
//   _init.OnClick += a.OnClick; -> _init.OnClick [ m1, m2 ]
// the subscriber is m2 (!= m1)
a.Init();
```

Same applies if the `_init` changes from one instance of `A` to another (eg. is not a static member)

Take also a look to [Unsubscribe - MDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events#unsubscribing).